Resample filter in weka
I have a low amount of data instances in my data set. So, I tried the "resample" filter in Weka to increase the data amount and thus enhance the model performance. Is it okay to set the sample size percentage to 200? Because at that point I am getting a good correlation coefficient on the cross-validation test.
I want to know if the Resample filter works fine when setting the sample size percentage to 200.
And after using this filter will my model predict accurately?
Are there any other augmentation methods to enhance my model's performance because I have a low amount of data?

If you are using the Resample filter (supervised or unsupervised) as part of a FilteredClassifier meta-classifier setup, then it is safe to use.
If you are using it from the Preprocess panel, then you are generating duplicates in the overall dataset. When performing cross-validation on this augmented dataset, you will end up with some instances appearing in train and test splits. That could explain the improvements that you have seen.
An alternative to Resample is the SMOTE filter (separate package).

I tried to apply the SMOTE filter to increase the data amount. But it kept staying blurry and didn't allow me to apply it. All my data are numeric. Do you have any instructions to overcome this problem?

Ah, SMOTE may require a nominal class attribute. You can check its capabilities in the GenericObjectEditor dialog.

I tried. But in my dataset it has only 4 attributes. There is no any class attribute in case this is the regression. So I it doesn’t allow me to applying SMOTE filter. I just want to increase my data instances because I am getting low correlation coefficient in cross validation. I really appreciate any methods or suggestions to improve model’s performances?

SMOTE is a supervised filter and requires a nominal class attribute. Have you plotted your input variables against your class attribute? If there isn't any obvious correlation visible then there may not be any worthwhile information in your dataset. However, if it looks like something, you could try mathematical transformations of your variables, depending on the shape of the correlation with the class attribute (eg log) via MathExpression filter.
